# Self-join using a nested Query

Tags: mysql

Hello All if it is possible, how would one do a Self-join on a subquery?

This was my attempt

```
SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME AS FULLNAME
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'Nancy' AND LAST_NAME = 'Davolio') AS FNAME
    ON EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME = .FIRST_NAME AND EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME = EMPLOYEEE.FULLNAME;
```

This is the database which im self-referencing

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID     DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    LASTNAME        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    FIRSTNAME       VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
    TITLE       VARCHAR(30),
    TITLE_OF_COURTESY   VARCHAR(25),
    BIRTHDATE       DATE,
    HIREDATE        DATE,
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR(60),
    CITY        VARCHAR(15),
    REGION      VARCHAR(15),
    POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR(10),
    COUNTRY         VARCHAR(15),
    HOME_PHONE      VARCHAR(24),
    EXTENSION       VARCHAR(4),
    PHOTO       VARCHAR(255),
    NOTES       VARCHAR(2000),
    REPORTS_TO      DECIMAL(9),
    CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
);
```

If working the query should be able to find who an Employee Reports to given the employees first and last name

Ive made a similar query using a simple Self-join which does this

```
 SELECT B.FIRSTNAME, B.LASTNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE AS A,
    EMPLOYEE AS B
WHERE A.REPORTS_TO = B.EMPLOYEE_ID  AND A.FIRSTNAME = 'Nancy' AND A.LASTNAME = 'Davolio';
```

however, as mentioned before, this time around i need to do the same thing but using a Selfjoin on a subquery

Thankyou all for your time.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're missing the table name in `.FIRST_NAME`. And there is not `EMPLOYEEE.FULLNAME` column, `FULLNAME` is in the `FNAME` subquery, so it should be `FNAME.FULLNAME`.

Comment: Yea i accidently deleted that My bad. In essense im just trying to self join using a sub query

Comment: I suspect that DECIMAL(9) should be INT. And what about poor Constantine?

Answer (score 0):

The subquery should select `REPORTS_TO`, not the employee's names.

```
SELECT e.*
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
JOIN (
    SELECT REPORTS_TO
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'Nancy' AND LASTNAME = 'Davolio') AS f
ON e.EMPLOYEE_ID = f.REPORTS_TO
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3fyq33J1y11zWaVKigfNPP/0)

Comment: I did actually come around with something Similar to this, however it returns an Empty Set

Comment: Will do. Off topic question but does anyone know how to use more than 2 OR operands?

Comment: `WHERE col1 = 'a' OR col2 = 'b' OR col3 = 'c'`